# Is there an API for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, api

I'm wondering, if there's an API for Stack Overflow. I'm looking for API for site-wide statistics, per-user statistics, posting questions and answers, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow-api/info

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion This tag looks empty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/).